# modifying matrix multiplication in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, multiplication

I would like to have MATLAB perform matrix multiplication, where all multiply operations are replace by plus operation.

Here is an example:

```
a = [3,4; 5,6];
b = [1;2];

c = modified_multiplication(a,b); %  = [3+1+4+2 ; 5+1+6+2] =  [10 , 14].
```

How can I do this as efficient as the original * operation?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going to be to combine `bsxfun` with `sum`.

```
c = sum(bsxfun(@plus, a, b.'), 1);
%   10  14
```

The `bsxfun` call adds the first entry of `b` to all elements in the first row of `a` and the second entry of `b` to all the elements in the second row of `a`, etc..

```
bsxfun(@plus, a, b.')
%   4   6
%   6   8
```

Then the application of `sum`, sums down the columns.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, c = sum(bsxfun(@plus, a, b.'), 2); gives me exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

For `a` and `b` of arbitrary sizes, it can be done as follows:

```
c = bsxfun(@plus, sum(a,2), sum(b,1));
```

This exploits the associative property of addition: first compute the sum of each row of `a` and of each column of `b`, and then compute all pairwise additions.